# How to remove tr with date value after deleting all records in second table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one table that looks like this:

```
Date    
04/22/2016  
04/15/2016
```

And after I click on the date above I get my second table created. Look like this:

```
Date: 04/22/2016
Time Slots  
7:30 AM - 7:50 AM   delete
7:50 AM - 8:10 AM   delete
8:10 AM - 8:30 AM   delete
```

So I have my logic that remove time slots in my second table, also after last element is removed in second table I hide() that table with JQuery, but I'm missing one more thing. After I remove last element in second table I want to remove the date from my first table too. How I can do that? I do not have unique ID that I CA USE, only what I can  use is the date value. I tried something like this but that did not work:

first table HTML:

```
// I passed value from my query to my tr id
<tr id="~(PTC_DATE)">
   <td onClick="getSlots('~(PTC_DATE)')"><a href="#">~(PTC_DATE)</a></td>      
</tr>
```

JQuery to hide tr:

```
$j('#'+ptcDate).hide()
```

This code did not work for me. Error showed up: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #04/22/2016` I'm not sure if I can use date value as an id or something else is wrong in my code.

Comment: Are the date entries in the first table guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: Yes they are unique, duplicates are not allowed and possible to be created.

Comment: Use the date as ID then you can get dates you want to hide in first table by id and pragmatically hide them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attr* selector multiple times to target the element:

```
var str=ptcDate.split('/');
$j('tr[id*='+str[0]+'][id*='+str[1]+'][id*='+str[2]+']').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Having / in ID attribute will not work with JQuery or with native JavaScript.

change the ID of tr tag to something which does not contain / . 
It would be better if you try not to use special characters in attribute values.